# VB2010 for x in y equivalent

Tags: vb.net

Trying VB for the first time and need some help.

I have a list box that I would like to run the same task for each of the lostbox items when a button is clicked. In python i would use `for x in y:`

But what do i do for vb?

Code thus far

```
Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

Dim mesg As String
Dim pw As String
Dim id As String
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
 id = Me.ListBox2.Items(i).ToString
 mesg = TextBox1.Text.ToString()         
 pw = "S"
 MessageBox.Show(id & mesg & pw, "test")
Exit For

   Next
End Sub
```

So i want that message box for each item in the listbox once *ok* has been clicked

Answer (score 1):

VB has many, many ways to make a loop.

Seems you've encountered the `For...Next` loop construct.

Python's `for x in y` sounds like VB's `For Each...Next` loops:

```
Dim message As String = TextBox1.Text;
Dim pw As String = "S";

Dim item As String
For Each item In ListBox2.Items
    MessageBox.Show item & message & pw, "test"
Next
```

I'd strongly recommend you read about [VB Loop Structures on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx)

Comment: This works to a dagree. If i have 2 items in my list it shows the first item twice although value is different.

Comment: You're saying you have 2 items and a `For Each` loop makes 3 iterations??

Comment: No im saying i have 2 items A & B. Ive converted the list to string. Now i get a message box with text A. Once closed another opens but with text A not text B

Comment: Well your code is getting the message text from `TextBox1.Text` (`Text` is already a `string`, the `ToString` call is redundant), which you're not updating between iterations, so `mesg` and `pw` are constant. Also you're not showing how your items are added so I only *presume* they're strings - if they're objects that don't override `ToString` then you're not getting the text of the item, but the name of the type, which isn't going to change at each iteration. `For Each` loops through all items of a collection, that's just how it works, confirmed by there being 2 iterations for 2 items.

Comment: I added values when i draged listbox to form. My aim is to get `id ` value to change each time in the message box others stay the same

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a for each loop. it's easier to read and to write and no need to worry about keeping track of iterations.

```
For Each listItem As ListBoxItem In ListBox2.Items
      // do your work with each item here
Next
```